# The smallest positive integer $n$ satisfying a given condition

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Given any positive integer $g$, what is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that 
$$\left\lceil \dfrac{(n-3)(n-4)}{12}\right\rceil>g.$$$\lceil x\rceil$ is a ceiling function of $x$.

Comment: Note that $\lceil x \rceil > g \iff x > g$.

Comment: @Goos: I think you should make an answer below. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As observed by $\textbf{Goos}$, the statements $\lceil{x}\rceil>g$ and $x>g$ are equivalent when $g$ is an integer. Using this, we can solve for $n$:

$$\left\lceil\dfrac{(n-3)(n-4)}{12}\right\rceil>g \iff \dfrac{(n-3)(n-4)}{12}>g \iff \underbrace{n^2-7n+12(1-g)}_{n=\frac{1}{2}\left(7\pm\sqrt{48g+1}\right)\text{ gives }0}>0$$
$$\text{smallest positive solution} \implies n=\left\lfloor\dfrac{1}{2}\left(7+\sqrt{48g+1}\right)\right\rfloor+1$$
$$\text{largest negative solution} \implies n=\left\lceil\dfrac{1}{2}\left(7-\sqrt{48g+1}\right)\right\rceil-1$$

When dealing with strict inequalities, rounding to integers should be treated with caution.